# elm list comprehensions, retrieving the nth element of a list

Tags: list, haskell, option-type, elm

I was trying to do a simulation of the Rubik's cube in Elm when I noticed [Elm](http://elm-lang.org/learn/Syntax.elm) doesn't support list comprehensions.   In Haskell or even Python I would write something like:

```haskell
ghci> [2*c | c <- [1,2,3,4]]

[2,4,6,8]
```

I could not find a way in Elm.  The actual list comprehension I had to write was (in Haskell):

```haskell
ghci> let x = [0,1,3,2]
ghci> let y = [2,3,1,0]
ghci> [y !! fromIntegral c | c <- x]

[2,3,0,1]
```

where `fromIntegral :: (Integral a, Num b) => a -> b` turns `Integer` into `Num`.

In Elm, I tried to use Arrays:

```elm
x = Array.fromList [0,1,3,2]
y = Array.fromList [2,3,1,0]
Array.get (Array.get 2 x) y
```

And I started getting difficulties with `Maybe` types:

```
Expected Type: Maybe number
Actual Type: Int
```

In fact, I had to look up what they were.  Instead of working around the maybe, I just did something with lists:

```elm
x = [0,1,3,2]
y = [2,3,1,0]

f n = head ( drop n x)
map f y
```

I have no idea if that's efficient or correct, but it worked in the cases I tried.

---

I guess my two main questions are:

- does Elm support list comprehensions? ( I guess just use `map`)
- how to get around the `maybe` types in the Array example?
- is it efficient to call `head ( drop n x)` to get the nth element of a list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Elm doesn't and will not support list comprehensions: https://github.com/elm-lang/Elm/issues/147

The style guide Evan refers to says 'prefer map, filter, and fold', so.. using `map:

```
map ((y !!).fromIntegral) x
```

or

```
map (\i-> y !! fromIntegral i) x
```

Commenters point out that (!!) isn't valid Elm (it is valid Haskell). We can define it as either:

`(!!) a n = head (drop n a)`, a total function.

or perhaps 

   `(!!) a n = case (head (drop n a)) of
        Just x -> x
        Nothing -> crash "(!!) index error"`

Comment: hi! what's that `!!` operator means? is that valid Elm?

Comment: Good question. It's an indexing operator in Haskell. Never seen it in Elm. Maybe the answerer just figured that the OP was going to define it. Still, I think the answer would have been A LOT better if that was pointed out: either the answer should show how to define `!!` in Elm or state what package it comes from.

Comment: You're right, it's not valid Elm.  `(!!) a n = head (drop n a)` is one defn, a total function.  or perhaps <br> `(!!) a n = case (head (drop n a)) of`
     <br> `    Just x -> x`
     <br> `    Nothing -> crash "(!!) index error"`

Comment: If this is something that many users want, maybe they should consider adding this functionality into the language? This seems kind of silly to me and these little things add up to turn a community off from adopting a language.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know much about Elm, so I can't answer to whether it supports list comprehensions (couldn't find anything via Google about it either way), but I can answer your other two questions.

> How to get around the Maybe types in the Array example?

The type of `Array.get` is `Int -> Array a -> Maybe a`, which means that it returns either `Nothing` or `Just x`, where `x` is the value at the given index.  If you want to feed the result of one of these operations into another, in Haskell you could just do

```
Array.get 2 x >>= \i -> Array.get i y
```

Or with do notation:

```
do
    i <- Array.get 2 x
    Array.get i y
```

However, from a quick search it seems that Elm may or may not support all monadic types, but hopefully you can still use a case statement to get around this (it's just not very fun)

```
case Array.get 2 x of
    Nothing -> Nothing
    Just i  -> Array.get i y
```

In fact, I would recommend writing a function to do this in general for you, it's just a direct clone of `>>=` for `Maybe` in Haskell:

```
mayBind :: Maybe a -> (a -> Maybe b) -> Maybe b
mayBind Nothing  _ = Nothing
mayBind (Just x) f = f x
```

Then you could use it as

```
Array.get 2 x `mayBind` (\i -> Array.get i y)
```

---

> Is it efficient to call `head (drop n x)` to get the nth element of a list?

No, but neither is direct indexing, which is equivalent to `head . drop n`.  For lists, indexing will always be `O(n)` complexity, meaning it takes `n` steps to get the `n`th element from the list.  Arrays have a different structure, which lets them index in logarithmic time, which is significantly faster.  For small lists (< 100 elements), this doesn't really matter, but once you start getting more than a hundred or a thousand elements, it starts becoming a bottleneck.  Lists are great for simple code that doesn't have to be the fastest, as they are generally more convenient.  Now, I don't know how exactly this gets translated in Elm, it may be that Elm will convert them into Javascript arrays, which are true arrays and indexable in `O(1)` time.  If Elm uses its own version of Haskell lists after it's been compiled, then you'll still have a slowdown.

Comment: Your `mayBind` function is equivalent to `Maybe.andThen`.